# How do you get the Angry Tiger in Saints Row IV?

Tags: saints-row-iv

How do you get the [Angry Tiger](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Angry_Tiger_(vehicle)) motorcycle in Saints Row IV? I couldn’t find anything on the wiki or online in general.

Comment: What is this angry tiger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angry Tiger is part of the Genki Vehicle Pack, which you get for completing Asha's loyalty mission.  Once you have the pack, you'll have access to all of the Genki vehicles.